# Twitter problem on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, twitter

I have a problem with the twitter login. I am doing the login with oauth. First login is good, and when I logout and make a relogin the twitter doesn't ask for my password and username, it gives the pin only. Is there a way to send logout to twitter? Because my logout is clears the NSUserDefaults only...

If I use the authorize link then I get the followin reponse:

403 Forbidden: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should call the End_Session method to log out.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-account%C2%A0end_session